# Can't create new vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For some reason I can't register new components. I got a few of them and when I try to register new one I get:

```
 Unknown custom element: <store> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

This is my app.js file:

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('register', require('./components/Register.vue'));
Vue.component('loginmodal', require('./components/LoginModal.vue'));
Vue.component('products', require('./components/Products.vue'));
Vue.component('store', require('./components/Store.vue'));
```

And Store.vue is basically duplicated Example.vue so no point in posting that. I tried using already created components on page like register for example and it works just fine for some reason. You should also know that I'm using Laravel where Vue is pre-included and already set up by default with example component already created.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to register all of your components globally?

Comment: and <example> doesn't give you this error?

Comment: @DavidL app.js file is going to be included globally and all components are compiled there so is there a reason not to ?

Comment: @thanksd Yeah, and every other component I created works fine

Comment: @Michael based on how you're structuring it, yes that seems to be the correct approach, although if you're using .vue files, it is preferable to let the components register their dependencies directly but these all may be top level dependencies.

Comment: @DavidL Yeah, unfortunately I can't get components to work now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my guess: you are using the component `store` in one of the other components listed above before registering it globally.

This could probably be adressed by changing your registering order, but I would advise you to register them locally to each component instead.

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html